# Debian 9 apt-get update returns error file system read only

Tags: debian

SOLVED: I have let it be for couple of hours and all of the sudden it works again. Dont know why.

I ran into a problem after mounting and unmounting the VMware Tools disk, and I have space left on the hard drive so that is not the issue.
When running `apt-get update` (or any apt command that involves write action on the file system) it returns the following error:

```
Ign:1 http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Bra:3 http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Fel:4 http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.e9QnPU for passing config to apt-key
Läs:2 http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [88,5 kB]
Läs:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [62,9 kB]
Fel:2 http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.ybseOZ for passing config to apt-key
Fel:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.1eqo60 for passing config to apt-key
Hämtade 151 kB på 0s (608 kB/s)
Läser paketlistor… Fel!
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stretch Release: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.e9QnPU for passing config to apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.ybseOZ for passing config to apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.1eqo60 for passing config to apt-key
W: Misslyckades med att hämta http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.1eqo60 for passing config to apt-key
W: Misslyckades med att hämta http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.ybseOZ for passing config to apt-key
W: Misslyckades med att hämta http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/Release.gpg  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.e9QnPU for passing config to apt-key
W: Vissa indexfiler kunde inte hämtas. De har ignorerats eller så har de gamla använts istället.
E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.se.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch_Release - mkstemp (30: Filsystemet endast läsbart)
E: Paketlistan eller statusfilen kunde inte tolkas eller öppnas.
```

I have tried running: `e2fsck -f /dev/sda2` but it returns the error that the system is mounted.
So I tried to mount it as read and write but without any further success.

I guess a solution to this could be to reinstall Debian but I have a web host and MySQL server on it and it would be a shame if it all would be lost.

This is my `kern.log`:

```
Aug 20 14:47:39 debian kernel: [49434.088879] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No partition found (2)
Aug 20 14:47:39 debian kernel: [49434.091270] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
Aug 20 15:07:30 debian kernel: [50624.369853] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Aug 20 15:08:06 debian kernel: [50661.286546] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Aug 20 15:09:20 debian kernel: [50734.996517] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Aug 20 15:10:39 debian kernel: [50813.404245] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Aug 20 15:11:34 debian kernel: [50868.840057] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

And a part of my syslog:

> ```
> Aug 20 22:39:31 debian systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Read-only file system
> Aug 20 22:39:31 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Clean php session files.
> Aug 20 22:39:31 debian systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
> Aug 20 22:40:01 debian CRON[22532]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
> Aug 20 22:40:01 debian CRON[22531]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
> Aug 20 22:41:01 debian CRON[22535]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
> Aug 20 22:41:01 debian CRON[22534]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
> ```

Comment: Look at your logs `kern.log` and `syslog`. It may have been remounted read-only after it has been identified as corrupt. Reboot and `fsck` your system.

Comment: @xhienne I have added the kern.log and a part of my syslog onto the post, I rebooted and it did not help I still can't run  fsck just gives me the error that it is mounted.

Comment: Thanks but the logs don't tell us anything. You didn't tell us how you tried to mount `/` read-write. Does `mount -o remount,rw /` yield an error?

Comment: In the syslog all it says is: `Aug 20 22:56:26 debian kernel: [78760.357474] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro` when doing the mount command. Same in kern.log.

Comment: And is `/` now writable?

Comment: Yes it seems like it, I can make a folder and a text file in there. But apt-get does still not work.

Comment: Maybe there are other filesystems like `/var` that are still mounted read-only. The main question is "why aren't they mounted read-write at boot". Check (or show us) your `/etc/fstab`, check for errors at boot, etc.

Comment: This is how it looked: https://gyazo.com/8c5435c009b66cbb28bc056b0fbecd1d the problem occurred after I mounted the VMware Tools CD then unmounted it.

Comment: Please add this to your question. In text form. You have no partition other than `/`. If your root FS is now writable, are the errors with `apt` still the same? If so, check if you have free space on your disk. Else update your question.

Comment: Yes the errors are still the same and I have space left on the disk.

Comment: Ok it has been solved somehow, I have let it be for 3 hours now and all of the sudden it works again... Weird.

Comment: If it's not that your /tmp is full or read-only, most likely something has broken your /tmp permissions. Try `chown root:root /tmp` and `chmod ugo+rwXt /tmp`

Comment: @JamiesonBecker this one - *chmod ugo+rwXt /tmp* worked for me

Comment: There is a quick workaround to get rid of this issue for a while : `sudo apt -o APT::Sandbox::User=root update`